# SLF4J exception when deploying to weblogic

Tags: grails, weblogic, slf4j

We've started getting the following exception when deploying to Weblogic:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
    'alertService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailMessageBuilderFactory': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailMessageContentRenderer': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groovyPagesTemplateEngine': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'gspTagLibraryLookup' while setting bean property 'tagLibraryLookup'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'filterInvocationInterceptor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterInvocationInterceptor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;
[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
```

I've tried removing the slf4j jar from my ear. I've also tried putting the following in my weblogic-appliction.xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>

<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```

Nothing has worked thus far. Basically, I've tried all of the different things that I've found online. Usually, when I have a conflict with a jar that I'm providing myself and that Weblogic is also providing, just using the prefer-application-packages does the trick.

I'm using Grails 2.3.6 with Weblogic 10.3.6.

Comment: It sounds like you understand the problem already but when you use something like JConsole to see what is in your classpath, do you see the same jar multiple times? You may need to play with your setDomainEnv.sh script or startWebLogic.sh script to set the classpath if `prefer-application-packages` isn't working

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this issue, this is what my problem ended up being:

What was happening is that we were including the activemq-all artifact for JMS stuff, and this artifact is what they call an "uber" jar. It as a ton of dependencies baked into it that cannot be excluded via maven – one of those dependencies was an old version of slf4j. So, even though I had the "prefer-application-packages" set in Weblogic for slf4j, it wasn't using the Grails provided version, but rather the activemq one. Rather than using the activemq-all dependency, I switched to use individual components from activemq and was able to at that point exclude slf4j. This solved my issue.